# LibreOffice: convert Calc spreasheet to pdf without filename and page number

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, convert

I would like to convert a few Calc spreadsheets to PDF format without having in the output the name of the document and the number of each page. I've looked at the options provided by the GUI "Export to pdf" and to the CLI parameters of "soffice --headless --convert-to", but no hints popped up. Is there any solution or workaround for this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

It's not very intuitive, but if you go to `Format -> Page Style` you can configure these sorts of things there.

So in your case, go to the `Header` and `Footer` tabs to turn them off.

Comment: Codlord, I followed you suggestion and it works,